# <Select> Down Arrow only works once

Tags: html, select

I have made a `<select>` drop down box for a website I have designed and it works great except for one problem. When I select the drop down "arrow" and select an option (any option) it filters results on the right hand side of the page. Great!! but when i try to select the "arrow" again nothing happens, the drop down will not display unless i click on the Name Bar/Option Display Name? (I'm not sure what you call it).

It is better if you see what I mean. I have posted a link to the website page I am inquiring about below. Just select an option from any three of the drop downs and once it filters try hitting the down arrow again.

Hopefully this is something you can help out with, it is minor but it does make the user experience a little frustrating at times.

[www.lunkerhunt.com/ourproducts.html](http://www.lunkerhunt.com/ourproducts.html)

Comment: It seems to work OK for me. Please state what browser (and version) you are testing on, and give us an exact sequence of steps ("Choose X from the top list, then y from the third list, then try to select z in the top list again") to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't see the example link.

Comment: skaffman deleted the link for some reason. Here it is: www.lunkerhunt.com/ourproducts.html

Answer (score 0):

You have a class that gives the ul of the right side a -40px margin on the left to account for 40px padding that shows up for some reason I could not find. When an item is selected the padding disappears so the right content overlaps the arrow part of the dropdown. If you change that class to:

```
.edukitList {
    margin: 0 auto 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It should work. Let me know if you have problems